# Varying Headerbox Color in baposter

Tags: posters, baposter

I'd like to have some boxes colored differently from others in a baposter. It seems like a natural way to do this is to allow a specification of some parameters (boxColorOne, borderColor, etc) in the options for headerbox, but I don't know how to make this happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A little example:

[image]

You can control the colors for the boxes using

- `borderColor=<color>` for the color of the border.
- `headerColorOne=<color>`, for the background color of the header of the boxes.
- `boxColorOne=<color>`, for the background color of the body of the boxes.

You can do this either as an argument for the `poster` environment so they will be the default settings but you can also control those attributes locally (for some chosen boxes) using the optional argument for the `posterbox` environment. I illustrate this in my example.

The code:

```
\documentclass[portrait,fontscale=1,margin=0.2cm,paperwidth=15truecm, paperheight=5cm]{baposter}


\begin{document}

\begin{poster}{
  headerheight=30pt,
  columns=5,
  background=none,
  linewidth=1pt,
  borderColor=green!60,
  textborder=rectangle,
  headershade=plain,
  headerColorOne=green!60,
  headerfont={},
  height=bottom,
  boxColorOne=lightgray,
}{}{Some text}{}{d}

\begin{posterbox}[column=0,headerfont={},headershape=rectangle]{rectangle}
Some test text
\end{posterbox}

\begin{posterbox}[column=1,headerfont={},headershape=rounded,headerColorOne=cyan,boxColorOne=orange!20,borderColor=cyan]{rounded}
Some test text
\end{posterbox}

\begin{posterbox}[column=2,headerfont={},headershape=smallrounded,headerColorOne=orange,boxColorOne=cyan!30,borderColor=orange]{smallrounded}
Some test text
\end{posterbox}

\begin{posterbox}[column=3,headerfont={},headershape=roundedleft,headerColorOne=yellow,boxColorOne=purple!10,borderColor=yellow]{roundedleft}
Some test text
\end{posterbox}

\begin{posterbox}[column=4,headerfont={},headershape=roundedright,headerColorOne=purple!60,boxColorOne=yellow!20,borderColor=purple!60]{roundedright}
Some test text
\end{posterbox}

\end{poster}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The posterbox environment is undefined for me (headerbox works). I really need to modify one of the boxes (either with headerbox or posterbox).

Comment: @Gonzalo Is it possible that in the code above, the paperwidth should be 15cm instead of 15truecm?