# Parallel box with different style in tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox, box

with many help in this forum, i was created one box with box inside.
i want to embed 3 boxes from link to my box: [Varying Headerbox Color in baposter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263166/varying-headerbox-color-in-baposter)
My box is attachment.
Thanks
[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,scalerel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{MnSymbol,wasysym}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols} 
\usepackage[format=plain,
            labelfont={bf,it},
            textfont=it]{caption} 
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{pifont}
\input{insbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\makeatletter
\tcbset{
    myhbox/.style 2 args={%
        enhanced, 
        boxsep = 0pt,
    left = 0pt,
    right = 4mm,
    top=0pt,
        breakable,
        colback=white,
        colframe=blue!30!black,
        attach boxed title to top left={yshift*=-\tcboxedtitleheight}, 
        title={#2},
        boxed title size=title,
        boxed title style={%
            sharp corners, 
            rounded corners=northwest, 
            colback=tcbcol@frame, 
            boxrule=0pt,
            %fontsize = 9pt,
        },
        underlay boxed title={%
            \path[fill=tcbcol@frame] (title.south west)--(title.south east) 
                to[out=0, in=180] ([xshift=5mm]title.east)--
                (title.center-|frame.east)
                [rounded corners=\kvtcb@arc] |- 
                (frame.north) -| cycle; 
        },
        #1
    },
     }


\makeatother


\newtcolorbox{myvbox}[2][]{%
    myvbox={#1}{#2}
}


\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\noindent


\begin{tcbposter}[
poster = {columns=2, rows=7, width=0.5\textwidth, height=0.5\textheight,spacing=0.1mm}]

\posterbox[width=12cm,height=5.8cm, myhbox={colframe=green!80!black}{AAA}]{column=1, row=6, rowspan=0.5,yshift=0.0cm,xshift=0cm}
{{
%\hspace*{0.2cm} 
\vspace*{0.2cm} 
\begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=2,raster rows = 1, raster force size=false,raster column skip=3mm]
\tcbitem [myhbox={leftmargin=0.4cm,colback=yellow!70!black, colframe=magenta!80!black,height=1.5cm,width=4cm}{\sum\$BBB}]
\tcbitem

\end{tcbitemize}
}
{
\begin{enumerate}
%\vspace*{0.2cm} 
\item ...................................
\item ...................................

\end{enumerate}
}}

\end{tcbposter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that the downvote does not come from me. However, I can understand why someone may want to downvote your question. You seem to be loading whatever package or library that ever crossed your path. On the other hand, this site is meant to provide information for everyone, not only to those who are asking questions. That is, others having a similar problem or question may want to learn from our correspondence. This will be hard if there are *many* unnecessary packages involved, the more so since these packages may not be compatible with each other.

Having said this, here comes my answer. Note, however, that due to the fact that you were loading so many packages, I had to make an ad hoc choice. I chose to do everything with the (extremely powerful) `tcolorbox` package. It is quite conceivable that there are alternative ways to achieve this, e.g. based on `baposter` as in the [answer you link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/263561/121799).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\makeatletter
\tcbset{
    myhbox/.style 2 args={%
        enhanced, 
        boxsep = 0pt,
    left = 0pt,
    right = 4mm,
    top=0pt,
        breakable,
        colback=white,
        colframe=blue!30!black,
        attach boxed title to top left={yshift*=-\tcboxedtitleheight}, 
        title={#2},
        boxed title size=title,
        boxed title style={%
            sharp corners, 
            rounded corners=northwest, 
            colback=tcbcol@frame, 
            boxrule=0pt,
            %fontsize = 9pt,
        },
        underlay boxed title={%
            \path[fill=tcbcol@frame] (title.south west)--(title.south east) 
                to[out=0, in=180] ([xshift=5mm]title.east)--
                (title.center-|frame.east)
                [rounded corners=\kvtcb@arc] |- 
                (frame.north) -| cycle; 
        },
        #1
    },
    plain/.style={colback=white,
        colframe=white}
     }


\makeatother


\newtcolorbox{myvbox}[2][]{%
    myvbox={#1}{#2}
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tcbposter}
 [poster = {columns=1, rows=2,spacing=0.1mm}]

\posterbox[width=\textwidth,height=5.8cm,top=0.2cm,left=4mm, myhbox={colframe=green!80!black}{AAA}]{}
{
\begin{tcbraster}[raster left skip=4mm,raster columns=2,raster rows = 2, raster force size=false,raster column skip=3mm]
\begin{tcolorbox}[myhbox={colback=yellow!70!black,
colframe=magenta!80!black,height=1.5cm,width=4cm}{$\sum\$BBB$}]
\end{tcolorbox}
%
\begin{tcolorbox}[plain,width=12cm]
 \begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=3,raster equal
 height,fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily]
  \tcbitem[title={First title},colframe=orange,colback=blue!10] First box
  \tcbitem[title={Second title},colframe=yellow,colback=red!10,sharp
  corners=northeast] Second box
  \tcbitem[title={Third title},colframe=red!20!gray,colback=yellow!20,sharp
  corners=northwest]
  Third box
 \end{tcbitemize}
\end{tcolorbox} 
\end{tcbraster}
{
\begin{enumerate}
\item \dotfill
\item \dotfill
\end{enumerate}
}}
\end{tcbposter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For the future, I would like to kindly ask you to

- remove all unnecessary packages,
- make sure that the code posted in your question can be compiled,
- and tell us which step you have a problem with (rather than just drawing a sketch that indicates what you want).

Of course, such sketches are extremely helpful, but they should come in combination with a description of the problem you are facing such that others can learn from our posts.

Comment: how can i edit distance betweeen (left box BBB) and box AAA) and distance between (left box First title) and box BBB. Thanks

Comment: @BVOT The distance to the left is determined by `raster left skip=4mm,` and one way to increase the vertical distance between AAA and BBB is to add `\vspace*{3mm}` before `\begin{tcbraster}`. I'm sure that there is a more elegant way but this works.